# Can a low rep user ask a moderator to set a bounty for a question?

Tags: support, flags, bounties, unanswered-questions

I have a question with no answers on Stack Overflow.

Can I flag the question and ask a moderator to set a bounty on it, because I don't have enough reputation to start a bounty on my own?

Comment: Flag is surely not the correct way, however with 20 rep you can become active in chat, get to know some other users there, and when earning their trust/respect, you can ask one of them (in the chat) if they might start a bounty.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but is that really a *programming* question about MetaSploit? Otherwise, it might belong on another site in the network.

Comment: @Glorfindel If you really think that can you tell which site it should  belong to and help me migrate the question to that site?

Comment: I was thinking about [security.se], it has [quite a few metasploit questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/metasploit). I hope somebody else can tell me if my guess is right.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Yes I acted upon your advice and found out that my question is not still available for bounty (13 hours remaining).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Can you give another piece of advice? As this question has got 10 down votes, shouldn't I delete this question?

Comment: @cstayyab solution to the problem, changes the problem, right? Well, you could use those 13 hours to get another 25 suggested edits approved (so that your bounty could be +100). And BTW you cannot delete this question anymore. To get rid of the downvotes, try to improve it (without changing the meaning of your question, to avoid it would invalidate existing answers). That might help to have some downvoters to un-downvote it, maybe even upvote it...

Comment: @cstayyab please review the edit I just applied to the title of your question. To better reflect what your question is about. If you do not like it, just perform a rollback (no problem).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I guess I am OK with the edit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, that would not be appropriate, and the flag is very likely to be declined. Moderators are elected/appointed to ... moderate ... the site, and putting bounties on questions isn't one of their tasks. They'd have to pay the bounty from their own reputation, and just like other users, they can only have three active bounties at a time. Just imagine what would happen if *all* users would start requesting this ...

This FAQ entry: [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/295232) contains some additional ideas for how to draw more attention to your question.

(Anecdotally, I remember a handful of cases where a ♦ moderator did post a bounty on somebody else's question because (s)he thought the question deserved it, not to gain any personal benefit from it. This is an exception though, and most certainly not limited to ♦ moderators.)

Answer (score 2):

> ... because I don't have enough reputation to start a bounty on my own ...

*Some people have dreams ... others wake up and work (hard) on it ...*

Looking at your current "reputation" on SO, you're only missing 2 more reputation points to actually earn the privilege to [Set bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). So just find any post (question or answer) for which you can think of an appropriate "suggested edit", get such edit approved, and you'll earn the missing reputation. With that, you can create a bounty of `+50` already.

Important: as mentioned in the comment below this answer by [Mari lou A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/223820/mari-lou-a), make sure the edits you suggest do get approved. Because trivial and poor/incorrect suggested edits are a quick way of getting banned from suggesting edits in the future also.

***Easy, no?***

PS 1: get another 25 similar edits approved to be able to create another bounty of `+50` ...

PS 2: For a user who only has `+1` rep, it *only* takes 37 "suggested edits" to get approved `(37*2)+1=75` ...

Comment: I see you did a little [self-promotion on a wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/7054/15). Is that acceptable protocol around here? I mean, linking faqs to one's own answer, especially when there's another answer that has +14 upvotes.

Comment: How does your answer help a user who only has 1 rep?

Comment: @Mari-LouA see my updated answer (the PS 2 I added). About the wiki edit: It did not say anything about users with rep below "+75" ... and since it is a wiki-post anybody is allowed to improve it, no? Moreover, the other answer here does not say anything about users with rep below "+75".

Comment: Very trivial and poor/incorrect suggested edits are a quick way of getting banned from suggesting edits in the future also. You make it sound so easy but for a newcomer, it must be daunting the idea to edit posts on Stack Overflow. A much better suggestion would be to say that the user "answers" a question to the very best of their ability.

Comment: Note that if the user has put a bounty of 50 on a question, then the next bounty for the same question can be only 100 or more, not 50 again. The system prevents putting the same/lower amount of bounty on the same question.

Comment: @Somewhat you're correct. Feel free to suggest another edit of my answer, should you want to do so.